# Listview show perfect but listview onclick not working?

Tags: android

```
 final ListView listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.item);
        ViewGroup headerView=(ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header,listView,false);
        listView.addHeaderView(headerView);
        contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(this,R.layout.row_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(News.this, details_Activity.class);
            String json_string = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            intent.putExtra("name", json_string);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    json_string = getIntent().getExtras().getString("json");
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
        int count = 0;
        String name,email,mobile;
        while (count<jsonArray.length()) {
            JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            name = JO.getString("name");
            email = JO.getString("email");
            mobile = JO.getString("mobile");

            Contacts contacts = new Contacts(name,email,mobile);
            contactAdapter.add(contacts);
            count++;

        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: Sumit can you share the error that you are getting ?

Answer (score 1):

From what I am looking in your code you are passing the intent key as
"name"

```
   intent.putExtra("name", json_string);
```

and while requesting you are using the wrong key "json"

```
json_string = getIntent().getExtras().getString("json");
```

instead you should use

```
json_string = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
```

Comment: Pass json data of listview to next activity on click